Как добиться, чтобы собственный WebView в андроид вызывался из других приложений
В моем проекте две Activity: MainActivity и BrowserActivity. Я, собственно, попробовал повторить 32 урок Виноградова про WebView (https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/72-urok-32-pishem-prostoj-brauzer.html), там все исходники. Единственное отличие в моем коде - это файл манифеста - пришлось добавить в него для "intent-filter" строку категории "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE",
без которой android studio ругалась.
Проблема в том, что при попытке вызвать Intent, который должен искать ВСЕ доступные на девайсе активности по доступу в интернет, вызывается ТОЛЬКО Chrome на моем "Galaxy A53 5G",
а вовсе не список из собственного WebView (описанного в уроке) и прочих присутствующих на девайсе браузерах. В чем тут собака порылась? Может, кривой манифест? Буду признателен за ответ.
Алексей.
На всякий случай привожу все исходники проекта:
AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Vinogradov_Studies3">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="MyBrowser" android:name=".BrowserActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
<!--                <action android:name="com.example.study32.Browser"></action>-->
                <data android:scheme="http"></data>
                <data android:scheme="https"></data>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

MainActivity.java
package com.example.study32;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        (findViewById(R.id.btnWeb)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();//"com.example.study32.Browser");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru"));
                startActivity(intent);
//                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru")));
            }
        });
    }
}

browse.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>

BrowserActivity
package com.example.study32;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class BrowserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String TAG = "MyTag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "BrowserActivity: onCreate()");
        webView.loadUrl(data.toString());
    }
}
 


Покажите свой фильтр и каким интентом пытаетесь его вызвать.

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.ya.ru"));
startActivity(intent);

Возможно у вас хром назначен браузером по-умолчанию, попробуйте вызвать выбор принудительно: startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open with..."));

Вызвал как Вы сказали (вместо startActivity(intent)  вызвал Ваш вариант)- получилось то же самое(выбора предложено не было) - сразу переход на сайт ya.ru! Даже удивительно. Хром стоит по дефолту(это я проверил).  Странно!

Короче, единственный способ, которым я могу вызвать мой собственный WebViw - это вызывать Activity, с которым этот WebView связан, а именно:
startActivity(Intent, BrowserActivity.class)
Во всех остальных случаях вызывается дефолтный хром, а списка для выбора не появляется.
